# Specify directories to check by the PGFplots addplot command

Tags: pgfplots

When I produce a graph with `PGFplots`, I first test it, before importing it in my main document `tex` file.

I have the file `tikzpicture.tikz` in which the tikzpicture environment data is included, and I have the file `tikzpicture_standalone.tex` with the minimal content

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \input{tikzpicture.tikz}
\end{document}
```

to 'test' the picture.

In `tikzpicture.tikz` I use the command `\addplot{table.txt}`, where `table.txt` is in the same directory. The testing goes fine.

When I then use the \input command to call `tikzpicture.tikz` in my main `tex` file, which is in another directory, it obviously does not work as `table.txt` is not in the same directory anymore. I have to use `path/table.txt` instead.

Changing this for all table data every time is annoying and inefficient, so I was wondering if there is a way to let the `\addplot` command check the local directory too, for the file `table.txt`. Then, I would not need to add the file paths all the time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method suggested in

[pgfplots from file: search path, looking for \graphicspath equivalent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35863/)

to tell `pgfplots` the path of your data files. You have to specify a global path starting from root folder so `pgfplots` looks in the right folder independently from where is compiled.