# Plot directly from .csv file

Tags: pgfplots, errors, csv

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
   title=Stress vs. Strain,
   xlabel={Strain $\Delta$ (\si{\milli\meter})},
   ylabel={Load $F$ (\si{\newton})},
   xmin=-0.30,
   ymin=0,
   %grid=major,
               ]
  \addplot+[smooth,mark=none]table[x=Strain1, y=Load, col sep=comma 
   {SpecimenA1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In the csv file I have two columns: "Stress" and "Strain." Whenevever I try 
to quick build I get the error of "Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'SpecimenA1' in 'search pat." What is wrong?

Comment: This example does not really help as it won't compile. Please make it a complete minimal working example (MWE) to show us the problem.

Comment: Where is the file located and what's theextension of the file?

Comment: I guess you simply missed to add the file extension of your file, i.e. write `SpecimenA1.csv` instead of just `SpecimenA1`.

Comment: I am new to Latex, as I only use it to write reports. It is inside of my folder that contains my lab report. The file is a .csv file

Comment: I receive even more errors when I add the file extension. \GenericError

Comment: Sorry, but with that information we cannot help you. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) as e.g. given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286886. To do so, please edit your question accordingly.