# Help including images in subfolder with tikz, \includegraphics not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, input

I have the following file organization:
Main/figures

in 'Main/' I have my main.tex file,  in 'Main/figures/' I have a .tikz file and a image.png image that gets included in the tikz file.

The path written in the tikz file is generated automatically and it points to the local folder, but when I load from the Main folder the tikz file, it fails to find the png image, as it tries to search locally.

I can fix this error by setting the path to "figures/image.png" instead of just "image.png", but I want to avoid doing so, as ideally I would like to external people to use these files without further knowledge on how to arrange them.

Minimal example:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\input{figures/tikzfile.tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**tikzfile.tikz**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5cm,height=5cm]
\addplot graphics [includegraphics cmd=\pgfimage,xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1]
 {image.png};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Error**

(there are several nonesense errors like "missing $ inserted." There is a warning "File "image.png" not found when defining image "pgflastimage". Tried all extensions in ".pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:" )

**Handmade fix I want to avoid**

modify in the tikzfile.tikz: {image.png} to {figures/image.png}.

**Attempted methods**

I've found in SE the use of \graphicspath as an alternative to search for the figures, but it doesn't works in my case.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35863/pgfplots-from-file-search-path-looking-for-graphicspath-equivalent)  they have a similar problem to include a table.dat, the suggested change seems to apply just for tables in the \addplot command. Trying to modify the solution
    \pgfplotsset{
        table/search path={plots/data},
    }

from "table" to "graphics", doesn't works.

Comment: Please provide an example we can compile which will give the error and tell us the exact text of the error message. 'Not working' could mean a number of things. However, I suspect that you are confusing two different ways of including external images: one is supplied by `graphicx` and the other by `pgf`. `\graphicspath` will have no effect on the inclusion of graphics using the PGF mechanism, as far as I know.

Comment: You could add `figures` to your input path. If it doesn't exist, it won't hurt anything, but it will cause TeX to search there, as well as everywhere else. Does it not work to use `\includegraphics` here rather than `\pgfimage`?

Comment: That is more or less what I want to achieve, but with \pgfimage. \includegraphics is not really what I want to use. The presented example is a minimal working one with my issue, but I'm actually making heavy use of the capabilities of \pgfimage with tikz.

Comment: Why? Are you masking images? That's the only good reason I can think of. Other than that, the Ti*k*Z manual itself recommends using `graphicx` instead. Like I said, you can add it to TEXINPUTS regardless.

Comment: (I'm unsure what you mean by masking and Image) These are matplotlib generated 2d plots which I turned into Tikz files with a matplotlib2tikz script. In this process the script generates a Png file with the 2d plot, together the Tikz file that contains all the rest (axes information, colorbar settings, etc) . Afterwards, by modifying the Tikz file,  I changed colorbar plots sizes and re scaled the  xticks values. The reescaling is non standard and I couldn't find a way to do it directly from matplotlib. Would this be possible with graphicx and texinputs?

Comment: You can use the texinputs method with `\pgfimage`. I'd expect you could alternatively do the scaling with `\includegraphics` - as far as I know, the masking stuff is the main thing `\pgfimage` has which `\includegraphics` doesn't. In the latter case, you can either use `\graphicspath` or you could set texinputs, so you have an additional option for helping TeX find the PNG. Masking can be used if, for example, you want to show an image as if it had holes in it or if you want so create a fading effect, so that the image is more (or less) opaque in some parts than others. You make a black ...

Comment: ... and white image known as a 'mask'. The black and white image tells the viewer how transparent or opaque each pixel should be. PGF's image handling lets you specify a mask which should be applied to the image. `graphicx` doesn't offer this functionality.

Comment: @pancho Still open or solved?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Not solved, I did the handmade  fix.