# Tikz equivalent of \graphicspath

Tags: tikz-pgf

The Tikz command `\draw plot file{data/filename.dat}` draws a line through the coordinates stored in filename.dat, which is contained in the subfolder data. Is there a Tikz equivalent to `\graphicspath{{./data/}}` so that I don't have to write `data/` in front of every plot command?

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35863/pgfplots-from-file-search-path-looking-for-graphicspath-equivalent) shows how to it with the pgfplots package, but I'm wondering if there is a Tikz native way for the same feature. I don't really want to load the entire pgfplots package just to avoid typing `data/`.

Here is an MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data/somedata.dat}
1 2
3 4
5 6
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./data/}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw plot file{somedata.dat};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [`prefix=data/`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#tikz/prefix)?

Comment: Perhaps? Where would one add this? `\tikzset{every plot/.style={prefix=data/}}` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `\tikzset{every plot/.style={prefix=data/}}` only applies to plots that are generated with GNUplot through the `plot function` operation. To apply the prefix to plots from data points in a file, one can add the following code to the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@plot@file ile#1{\def\tikz@plot@data{\pgfplotxyfile{\tikz@plot@prefix#1}}\tikz@@@plot}
\makeatother
\tikzset{every plot/.style={prefix=data/}}
```

This really just adds the `plot/prefix` key, which is stored in `\tikz@plot@prefix`, to the file name that is passed to `plot file`. There are probably better ways to patch this because this will break if the `plot file` operation is ever reimplemented. But for now it works.